# Can DataTable.WriteXML cause high CPU usage?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, string-concatenation, processing-efficiency

I have a web service that intermittently uses up to 100% CPU on the server. We cannot replicate this on the development server, it only seems to happen on production. We thought it might be a load issue, but we have been testing it on development with up to 10 people at a time. On production there is only 2 people using it, in it's beta state. I have scoured the code for any infinite loops and there are none.

After lots and lots of searching I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307340) page that says that string concatenation may be the issue. There are 5 places that used a `StringWriter`, which I have changed to `StringBuilder` as advised in the link there. But the issue still occurs and am wondering if it may be the `DataTable.WriteXML` calls. Basically every method in the web service fills a data table and returns the data as XML as this is the required format for the third party. The calls are all like:

```
Dim SB As New StringBuilder
Dim SW As New IO.StringWriter(SB)
dsSource.Tables("Test").WriteXml(SW, Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema, True)
```

Is this inefficient? Would this cause 100% CPU usage? If it could be the cause, what alternative would be best?

I would love to run some monitoring on this, but the fact of the matter is it happens maybe once a week, it's only on the live server, so if I take the time to run some performance diagnostics it is time that the service isn't running and our users can't get their work done. It is much quicker and simpler to kill the process and regenerate it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does this production web server only have 1 CPU? I ask because the WriteXML, like any syncronous/single threaded code, will use 100% of a single CPU.  If the server has multiple CPUs, and it jumps to 100 and stays there a while, this is likely something else. Look at stuff like multiple threads (running too many) or cleaning up after yourself, IE;

```
SW.flush
SW.Close
SW = Nothing
```

Or put it in a USING block

```
USING SW As New IO.StringWriter(SB)
'Your code here
END USING
```

Comment: The server is quadcore, CPU will stay at 100% until the process is killed. I am cleaning up the `StringWriter` after use by the exact means you mention.

Comment: I would put in some code to write certain events to a log so you can find where the problem really is. As it is, we are just shoting in the dark, hoping to hit the answer.  Then, when it locks up at 100%, you can review your log to see what DIDN'T happen, telling you where it is.